# How to wait until all requests are handled in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

We can start Flask by using the `flask run` command. And we can easily stop it using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. I notice that when stopping the Flask app, the process do not wait for anything. Imagine we have a route:

```py
@app.route("/download")
def download_large_file():
    ...
```

This function returns a large file that will take a long time to complete. Is there any way we can ask Flask to stop handling any new requests, while wait for the current requests to be finished before the termination?

Comment: That would probably have to be done in the server on top of it. For example with [waitress](https://pypi.org/project/waitress/) you could `waitress_server.task_dispatcher.shutdown(timeout=30)` or so to achieve that. Don't know about flask's own debug server though.